# Archive pom.xml Maven Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I am changing a project of type: Java Web Project to a Type Project: Maven Web Project and I have problems with the pom.xml file and dependencies.

**pom.xml**

```
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
     </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

And Netbeans generates this error:

```
  **Could not find artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-   annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final in unknown-jars-temp-repo**
```

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like net beans add repository `unknown-jars-temp-repo` for dependencies it could not identify. Check [this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219418).

However, your problem looks to be incorrect group id of `hibernate-commons-annotations`. It should be `org.hibernate.common` and not `org.hibernate` if you would like it to be downloaded from [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate.common%7Chibernate-commons-annotations%7C4.0.2.Final%7Cjar).

Go and search [maven central](https://search.maven.org/) if you face similar problem.